# Trouble using barButtonItem for popoverPresentationController in iOS 9?

Tags: ios

I've had some code using the new UIAlertController class that's been working just fine in iOS 8.  It now crashes in iOS 9, with the following error message:

```
2015-07-23 10:38:27.499 MyApp[828:563509] -[UITabBarItem _viewForPresenting]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x157644960
2015-07-23 10:38:27.500 MyApp[828:563509] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITabBarItem _viewForPresenting]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x157644960'
```

The problem seems to be using the barButtonItem field to configure the popoverPresentationController, instead of just using the sourceView/sourceRect thing.  If I switch to the latter, it's fine (but of course, the action sheet doesn't pop up from where I wanted it to pop up).  Googling the error message has come up blank so far.

Here is the code.  It's pretty basic, nothing fancy going on here:

```
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"What do you want to do?" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Clear Call History" style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        [self confirmClearCallHistory];
    }]];
    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}]];
    [alertController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPopover];

    //if I do this (like I want to), it crashes:
    [alertController popoverPresentationController].barButtonItem = self.tabBarController.callsTab;

    // if I do this, it's fine:
    // [alertController popoverPresentationController].sourceView = self.editButton;
    //  [alertController popoverPresentationController].sourceRect = self.editButton.bounds;

    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Anybody else had similar issues?  It's the same in all three iOS 9 betas so far...

(Oh, and I should mention it only crashes on iPad, not on iPhone... but that's not surprising, because the presentation mode for an action sheet is a no-op on the iPhone, i.e. all action sheets are presented the same no matter what)

Comment: i have the same issue, but still didn't found a solution... Did you?

Answer (score 3):

Oh cool! It looks like you can set a source bar button item on UIPopoverPresentationController.

```
popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = myBarButtonItem
```

I did this and it works perfectly without any need for digging through private subviews.

According to the documentation, this has been available since iOS 8. So it has always been there in iOS 9 as well.

Comment: This is the correct answer! `BarButtonItem` doesn't inherit from `UIView`, so this is why it's needed instead of `sourceView`.

I wish this was better stated in the docs, unless I missed it somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, interesting.  I'm actually passing a UITabBarItem instance into the barButtonItem field.  (I inherited the older code, so I wasn't aware of this)  Somehow, that actually worked on iOS 8?  Go figure.

So yeah, can't do that I guess.  heh.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the approach I use.  I get the view value from the UIBarButtonItem and use it as the source view.

```
 func settingsButtonAction(sender:UIBarButtonItem) {
        let viewController = UIViewController()
        viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
        if let presenter = viewController.popoverPresentationController {
            let targetView = sender.valueForKey("view") as! UIView
            presenter.sourceView = targetView;
            presenter.sourceRect = targetView.bounds;
        }
        presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your handler method if you have sender as 'AnyObject'.
You can directly apply,

```
alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sender.bounds
alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender as? UIView
self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```